# VisualStudio.com Unit Tests are failing because they can't reach SQL Azure

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, azure, continuous-integration, azure-sql-database

I've setup a VisualStudio.com build definition to build a solution on a checkin trigger, execute unit tests, and if all tests complete successfully to deploy the solution to an Azure AppService. The unit tests fail because the Azure SQL Database instance cannot be reached.

Are there any additional configuration steps that need to be completed to allow unit tests that are executed from VisualStudio.com to access Azure SQL DB instances?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to open the firewall between VSTS and your Azure SQL DB, but it's probably a good time to be taking a look at your unit test strategy.  If your unit tests have a dependency on hitting a database, they likely also cause or are impacted by side effects and are really integration tests.  I'd recommend refactoring your tests to have them be more isolated, but as an interim solution have you considered (assuming Entity Framework) using the in memory provider?

Comment: You're correct, I used the wrong terminology. These are actually integration tests. Opening the Azure SQL Database firewall could be the missing step - how would I go about determining what IP address or subnet range to open?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the configurations and changes in settings required, and possible workarounds explained in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/08/26/data-driven-load-tests-using-visual-studio-online-and-sql-azure/) article.

Hope this helps.